# Document is not defined error for 'document.getElementById()'

Tags: javascript, html, css, getelementbyid

Essentially, I keep getting the message "document is not defined" when I run my .js doc on command line. I'm trying to create a super basic game where the user helps the squirrel get to the chestnuts by using arrow keys. So far I can't move the squirrel yet, and I suspect it has to do with the document is not defined error that I'm getting (lines 1-3 and maybe also 52 in the link).

You can find my code (html, css and js) in the following [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/8Lbkcsq2/)

(http://jsfiddle.net/8Lbkcsq2/)

```js
var squirrelImg = document.getElementById("squirrelImg");
var forest = document.getElementById("forest");
var chestnutImg = document.getElementById("chestnutsImg");

var squirrel = {
    name: "Mr. Squirrel",
    has_chestnuts: false,
    hungry: true
};

var chestnuts = {
    name: "chestnuts"
};

var positionLeft = 0;
var positionTop = 0;

function move(e) {
    // 39 for right arrow
    if (e.keyCode === 39) {
        if (positionLeft < 850) {
            positionLeft += 50;
            squirrelImg.style.left = positionLeft + "px";
        }
    }
    // 40 for down arrow
    if (e.keyCode === 40) {
        if (positionTop < 600) {
            positionTop += 50;
            squirrelImg.style.top = positionTop + "px";
        }
    }
    // 37 for left arrow
    if (e.keyCode === 37) {
        positionLeft -= 50;
        if (positionLeft < 0) {
            positionLeft += 50; // CHANGE TO +=50 LATER
        }
        squirrelImg.style.left = positionLeft + "px";
    }
    // 38 for up arrow
    if (e.keyCode === 38) {
        positionTop -= 100;
        if (positionTop < 0) {
            positionTop += 50; // CHANGE TO +=50 LATER
        }
        squirrelImg.style.top = positionTop + "px";
    }
    foundChestnuts();
}

document.onKeyDown = move();

function foundChestnuts() {
    if ((squirrelImg.style.top == "300px") && (squirrelImg.style.left == "750px")) {
        squirrel.has_chestnuts = true;
        alert("Thank you for helping Mr. Squirrel find his chestnuts!");
        var eat = confirm("Should Mr.Squirrel eat his chestnuts?");
        if (eat === true) {
            alert("Time to eat!");
            alert("Yum! Mr. Squirrel isn't hungry anymore!");
        } else {
            alert("I guess Mr. Squirrel can wait a little longer...");
        }
    } else {
        squirrel.has_chestnuts = false;
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #b5916c;
}
h3 {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
p {
    font-family:'Dancing Script', cursive;
    font-size: large;
}
#forest {
    background-image: url(http://s21.postimg.org/jyht762hj/forestfloor.jpg);
    width: 850px;
    height: 600px;
    position: relative;
    /*opacity: 0.5;*/
}
#squirrelImg {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(http://s24.postimg.org/wkqh9by4x/squirrel.png);
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#chestnutsImg {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(http://s28.postimg.org/kgiubxhnd/chestnuts.jpg);
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    left: 750px;
    top: 300px;
}
```

```html
<body>
     <h3>A Plea from Mr. Squirrel:</h3>

    <p>My dearest human,</p>
    <p>I seem to have misplaced my chestnuts and I am quite famished.</p>
    <p>Would you mind assisting me in locating them?</p>
    <p>Much obliged!</p>
    <div id="forest">
        <div id="squirrelImg"></div>
        <div id="chestnutsImg"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: *“Essentially, I keep getting the message "document is not defined" when I run my .js doc on command line.”* On the command line? Using what?

Comment: `document` is a part of the HTML API. Of course it won't be defined "on command line" (however it depends what the "command line" you are talking about). Also, your `move` function should be provided with an event, but in `document.onKeyDown = move();` you provided nothing.

Comment: @U2744SNOWFLAKE by typing in node filename.js on command line. I don't know if that's what you wanted to know? Haha, sorry. I wasn't kidding when I said I'm super new to these things >___<

Comment: You need a web browser. Node doesn’t have a document, won’t look at your HTML and CSS, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please place the script before `</body>`, or in `window.onload` callback function.
Because document object is not created when you call `document.getElementById`.

Yes, the problem is `document.onKeyDown = move()`. The right event handler is`document.onkeydown`, and handler should be a function `move`, not a function result `move()`. So just changed to `document.onkeydown=move`

Comment: `document` will be defined. It just won’t have all its content.

Comment: FYI, if there is no `document`, most probably there won't be `window` as well.

Comment: the script is included within the <body> tags in my actual code (I put it in a <script> tag after the div tags and before the </body> tag in my HTML). The way it's displayed separately above is mostly due to jsfiddle, I think. Thanks for confirming that I at least did that part right though! :)

Comment: I just change the code `document.onKeyDown = move();` to `document.onkeydown = move;`, then it works! From jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8Lbkcsq2/

Comment: OH WOWWWWW!!!! @TracholarZuo THAT WORKED!!!! Thank you so very very very much. So crazy how little things like using camel case rather than downcase and putting in a () when I shouldn't have just threw everything for a loop!

Comment: @claaang It should not be surprising that it worked after removing the execution `()`. Moreover it's recommended that you do not use `.onKeyDown`. Use `.addEvent Listener` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `move()` requires an event to be passed to it but when you do `document.onKeyDown = move();` no event is passed.

Change `document.onKeyDown = move();` to `document.addEventListener("keydown", move, false);`

[working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Lbkcsq2/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Add a event listener `document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {...}` instead of `document.onKeyDown = move()`.

<kbd>**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/8Lbkcsq2/3/)**</kbd>

```js
var squirrelImg = document.getElementById("squirrelImg");
var forest = document.getElementById("forest");
var chestnutImg = document.getElementById("chestnutsImg");

var squirrel = {
  name: "Mr. Squirrel",
  has_chestnuts: false,
  hungry: true
};

var chestnuts = {
  name: "chestnuts"
};

var positionLeft = 0;
var positionTop = 0;

document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  // 39 for right arrow
  if (e.keyCode === 39) {
    if (positionLeft < 850) {
      positionLeft += 50;
      squirrelImg.style.left = positionLeft + "px";
    }
  }
  // 40 for down arrow
  if (e.keyCode === 40) {
    if (positionTop < 600) {
      positionTop += 50;
      squirrelImg.style.top = positionTop + "px";
    }
  }
  // 37 for left arrow
  if (e.keyCode === 37) {
    positionLeft -= 50;
    if (positionLeft < 0) {
      positionLeft += 50; // CHANGE TO +=50 LATER
    }
    squirrelImg.style.left = positionLeft + "px";
  }
  // 38 for up arrow
  if (e.keyCode === 38) {
    positionTop -= 100;
    if (positionTop < 0) {
      positionTop += 50; // CHANGE TO +=50 LATER
    }
    squirrelImg.style.top = positionTop + "px";
  }
  foundChestnuts();
});

// combined 3 functions previously separated for foundChestnuts, eatChestnuts and hungerLevel into the function below
function foundChestnuts() {
  if ((squirrelImg.style.top == "300px") && (squirrelImg.style.left == "750px")) {
    squirrel.has_chestnuts = true;
    alert("Thank you for helping Mr. Squirrel find his chestnuts!");
    var eat = confirm("Should Mr.Squirrel eat his chestnuts?");
    if (eat === true) {
      alert("Time to eat!");
      alert("Yum! Mr. Squirrel isn't hungry anymore!");
    } else {
      alert("I guess Mr. Squirrel can wait a little longer...");
    }
  } else {
    squirrel.has_chestnuts = false;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #b5916c;
}
h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
p {
  font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
  font-size: large;
}
#forest {
  background-image: url(http://s21.postimg.org/jyht762hj/forestfloor.jpg);
  width: 850px;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  /*opacity: 0.5;*/
}
#squirrelImg {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(http://s24.postimg.org/wkqh9by4x/squirrel.png);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#chestnutsImg {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(http://s28.postimg.org/kgiubxhnd/chestnuts.jpg);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  left: 750px;
  top: 300px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h3>A Plea from Mr. Squirrel:</h3>

  <p>My dearest human,</p>
  <p>I seem to have misplaced my chestnuts and I am quite famished.</p>
  <p>Would you mind assisting me in locating them?</p>
  <p>Much obliged!</p>
  <div id="forest">
    <div id="squirrelImg"></div>
    <div id="chestnutsImg"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```